# What does @end do in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I always see it when I'm browsing through code and I have absolutely no idea what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It marks the end of an implementation of a class or interface.

Answer (score 3):

It finishes a declaration.

For example, when you implement an interface, you do:

```
@interface MyInterface

/* functions and stuff here */

@end
```

Comment: It finishes other constructs as well, not just an interface declaration.

Comment: One other nitpick - you don't declare functions in an Objective-C interface. Methods yes, but not functions.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, it was only an example, that's why I used the word "declaration" instead of another one. And yes, you're right, they are methods, I just missed that (English is not my main language, so sometimes I forget things like that). Thanks for your comments!